# Circular Wrapping text needs slight adjustment

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

You may not be able to tell that much but for some reason a few of the characters are being offset somehow, due to a flaw in my algorithm...If someone could figure out what is causing it, I would really appreciate it and any critique is welcome as I'm still very new at java.

[image]

Edit: If you look at the image above it's the E that is offset in WE on the left and right side

Edit: I think it may be in my calculation of the size of text vs size of circle

Edit: Ok so when I enter 600 for width and height everything seems to fall in place, but as it gets smaller from say 250 for example the characters start becoming more offset and overlapping

Main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/11/2014.
 */
public class Prog14_05 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create Pane
        circularText phrase = new circularText("WE ARE ANONYMOUS, " +
                "WE ARE LEGION, WE DO NOT FORGIVE, WE DO NOT FORGET ",
                480, 480);

        // Place clock and label in border pane
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(phrase.getTextSize() * 2));
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        pane.getChildren().add(phrase);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_05");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

circularText Class:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/11/2014.
 */
public class circularText extends Pane {
    double textSize = 30;
    String string = "";
    String fontName = "";
    Font font;
    // Pane's width and height
    private double w = 250, h = 250;

    /** Create Constructor */
    public circularText (String phrase, double w, double h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.string = phrase;
        textSize = (this.w / this.string.length()) * 2;
        Font font = new Font("Times Roman", textSize);

        paintText(this.string, this.font);
    }

    /** Set new font */
    public void setFont(String name) {
        Font font = new Font(name, textSize);
        this.font = font;
        this.fontName = name;
        paintText(this.string, this.font);
    }

    /** Return textSize */
    public double getTextSize() {
        return this.textSize;
    }

    /** Set textSize */
    public void setTextSize(double textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        Font font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        this.font = font;
        paintText(this.string, this.font);
    }

    /** Return pane's width */
    public double getW() {
        return w;
    }

    /** Set pane's width */
    public void setW(double w) {
        this.w = w;
        textSize = (this.w / this.string.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.string, this.font);
    }

    /** Return pane's height */
    public double getH() {
        return h;
    }

    /** Set pane's height */
    public void setH(double h) {
        this.h = h;
        textSize = (this.w / this.string.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.string, this.font);
    }

    /** Paint the Letters */
    protected void paintText(String phrase, Font font) {
        // Initialize parameters
        double radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.8 * 0.5;
        double centerX = w / 2;
        double centerY = h / 2;
        double size = radius / 4 - this.getTextSize();

        // Draw circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(centerX - size - textSize, centerY - size,
            radius);
        circle.setFill(null);
        circle.setStroke(null);
        getChildren().clear();
        getChildren().add(circle);

        // Place text in a circular pattern
        int i = 0;
        double degree = 360 / phrase.length();
        for (double degrees = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++, degrees += degree) {
            double pointX = circle.getCenterX() + circle.getRadius() *
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
            double pointY = circle.getCenterY() + circle.getRadius() *
                Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));
            Text letter = new Text(pointX, pointY, phrase.charAt(i) + "");
            letter.setFont(font);
            letter.setFill(Color.LIME);
            letter.setRotate(degrees + 90);
            getChildren().add(letter);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here is what I got so far, let me know what you all think and what can be improved upon...

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/11/2014.
 */
public class CircularText extends Pane {
    private double circleWidth;
    private double circleHeight;
    private double textSize;
    private double textStartDegree;
    private double textRotate;
    private double gapSpacing;
    private double offSetX;
    private double offSetY;
    private Font font;
    private Paint textFill;
    private String fontName;
    final String text;

    /** Default Constructor */
    public CircularText(String text) {
        this.circleWidth = 250;
        this.circleHeight = 250;
        this.text = text;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        this.font = new Font("Times Roman", textSize);
        this.textFill = Color.BLACK;
        this.textStartDegree = 240;
        this.textRotate = 90;
        this.gapSpacing = 0.975;
        this.offSetX = 4;
        this.offSetY = 3;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Create Constructor */
    public CircularText (String text, double w, double h) {
        this.circleWidth = w;
        this.circleHeight = h;
        this.text = text;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / (this.text.length()) * 2);
        this.font = new Font("Times Roman", textSize);
        this.textFill = Color.BLACK;
        this.textStartDegree = 240;
        this.textRotate = 90;
        this.gapSpacing = 0.975;
        this.offSetX = 4;
        this.offSetY = 3;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get font color */
    public Paint getTextFill() {
        return textFill;
    }

    /** Set font color */
    public void setTextFill(Paint textFill) {
        this.textFill = textFill;
        this.font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get starting position for text */
    public double getTextStartDegree() {
        return textStartDegree;
    }

    /** Set starting position for text */
    public void setTextStartDegree(double textStartDegree) {
        this.textStartDegree = textStartDegree;
        this.font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get letter rotation */
    public double getTextRotate() {
        return textRotate;
    }

    /** Set letter rotation */
    public void setTextRotate(double textRotate) {
        this.textRotate = textRotate;
        this.font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get spacing between ending and beginning of phrase */
    public double getGapSpacing() {
        return gapSpacing;
    }

    /** Set spacing between ending and beginning of phrase */
    public void setGapSpacing(double gapSpacing) {
        this.gapSpacing = gapSpacing;
        this.font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Get current font */
    public Font getFont() {
        return this.font;
    }

    /** Set new font */
    public void setFont(String name) {
        this.font = new Font(name, textSize);
        this.fontName = name;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return textSize */
    public double getTextSize() {
        return this.textSize;
    }

    /** Set textSize */
    public void setTextSize(double textSize, double offSetX, double offSetY) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.offSetX = offSetX;
        this.offSetY = offSetY;
        this.font = new Font(fontName, textSize);
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return circle's width */
    public double getCircleWidth() {
        return circleWidth;
    }

    /** Set circle's width */
    public void setCircleWidth(double w) {
        this.circleWidth = w;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Return circle's height */
    public double getCircleHeight() {
        return circleHeight;
    }

    /** Set circle's height */
    public void setCircleHeight(double h) {
        this.circleHeight = h;
        textSize = (this.circleWidth / this.text.length()) * 2;
        paintText(this.text, this.font);
    }

    /** Paint the Letters */
    protected void paintText(String text, Font font) {
        getChildren().clear();
        // Initialize parameters
        double radius = Math.min(circleWidth, circleHeight) * 0.8 * 0.5;
        double centerX = circleWidth / 2;
        double centerY = circleHeight / 2;

        // Place text in a circular pattern
        int i = 0;
        double degree = 360.0 / (text.length() / this.gapSpacing);
        for (double degrees = this.textStartDegree;
             i < text.length(); i++, degrees += degree) {
            double pointX = centerX + radius *
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees)) - (this.textSize) *
                this.offSetX;
            double pointY = centerY + radius *
                Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)) - (this.textSize) *
                this.offSetY;
            Text letter = new Text(pointX, pointY,
                String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)));
            letter.setFont(font);
            letter.setFill(this.textFill);
            letter.setRotate(degrees + this.textRotate);
            letter.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            getChildren().add(letter);
        }

    }
}
```

After testing this with Courier New font, it appears to render flawlessly. I also tested this with other fonts and everything still rendered correctly. It appears the flaw in my code was correlated with the Circle object I had created for troubleshooting and for some reason decided to use in my algorithm. After removing this Circle object and fixing small flaws in my code and adding flexibility, everything works perfectly :)

[image: Wrapping Text in a Circular Pattern]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/11/2014.
 */
public class Prog14_05 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create Pane
        CircularText phrase = new CircularText("TESTING MY CIRCULAR" +
                "TEXT OBJECT CLASS",
                500, 500);
        phrase.setFont("Courier New");
        phrase.setTextFill(Color.LIME);
        phrase.setTextSize(20);

        // Place clock and label in border pane
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(phrase.getTextSize()));
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        pane.getChildren().add(phrase);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_05");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

P.S Test my code and let me know if you find any bugs, Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: Note: If you have a problem with a the letters in a phrase being offset, try using a different font. I have reset the default font to "Courier New" because it seems to render any font of any size without offsetting the characters.

Answer (score 1):

My trig isn't very good so I can't help you there. I'm thinking the "W" may be offset, not the "E". I know in other versions of Swing the "W" has caused painting problems before, but I don't remember the details. So I might suggest trying different characters to see if you still have the same problem at those two locations.

Here is another example of circular painting that I found on the web a long time ago. I tried your text and the "WE" is overlapped. I changed the "W" to an "R" and it seems to work ok, so maybe this validates my above statement?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
//import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

public class SplashPortalPanel6 extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//    private static final char[] MESSAGE = "  SplashPortal.net".toCharArray();
    private static final char[] MESSAGE = "  WE ARE ANONYMOUS, WE ARE LEGION, WE DO NOT FORGIVE, WE DO NOT FORGET ".toCharArray();
//    private static final char[] MESSAGE = "  RE ARE ANONYMOUS, RE ARE LEGION, RE DO NOT FORGIVE, RE DO NOT FORGET ".toCharArray();

    private static final double R90 = Math.toRadians(90);
    private static final double R_90 = Math.toRadians(-90);

    private AffineTransform cumalativeRotation = new AffineTransform();
    private double rotation = Math.toRadians(360.0 / MESSAGE.length);

    private Font font = new Font("Impact",Font.ITALIC,40);

    private final Timer timer = new Timer(1000/76, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();//just repaint
        }
    });

    public SplashPortalPanel6() {
      setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
      setOpaque(false);
    }

    //This method is called when the panel is connected to a native
    //screen resource.  It's an indication we can now start painting.
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        timer.start();
    }
    public void removeNotify() {
        super.removeNotify();
        timer.stop();
    }

    private static final GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(0F, 0F, Color.BLUE, 5F, 10F, Color.CYAN, true);

    private static final int x = 0, y = 0, w = 100, h = 100;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.translate( getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 );
        cumalativeRotation.rotate(rotation/50);
        g2.transform( cumalativeRotation );

        for(int i = 0; i < MESSAGE.length; i++) {
            // fill the rectangle
            g2.translate(250, 0);
            g2.rotate(R90);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//            g2.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
            // draw the border
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//            g2.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
            // draw the character
            g2.setPaint(gradient);
            g2.drawChars(MESSAGE,i, 1, x+30, y+50);
            g2.rotate(R_90);
            g2.translate(-250, 0);
            g2.rotate(rotation);
        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowSplashScreen() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new SplashPortalPanel6());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
        //frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowSplashScreen();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note, if you uncomment the "fillRect" and "drawRect" statements you will see the original implementation of the code. Of course you will need to use the shorter first message string to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks @camickr I think you may have been right about the text rendering, I added javajon's code and the problem almost completely went away. I changed the font and you can't even tell now, so maybe it's font specific

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
    letter.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    letter.setWrappingWidth(100);
```

Not sure what is going on with JavaFX Text rendering.

The math appears correct.  For clarity when coding some suggest adding explicit typing to ensure your not mixing doubles with floats with ints.  So instead of

double centerY = h / 2;

do

double centerY = h / 2.0d;

(Also take out extra "this." clutter, many methods are not being used like "setH", and make class name upper case CircularText)

Comment: Alright, that didn't completely fix it but it looks a lot better now and the size of the circle no longer causes the text to become jumbled...However there is still a very slight offset, as camickr it may be a text rendering that is causing it. You can't really tell it's even offset really....Could be the specific font I'm using as well, I changed the font and it didn't seem to have that problem so it could just be font specific